# sequelize return blob as text

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am using Sequelize to retrieve data from a legacy mysql database. One of the columns in the table is a blob, so sequelize returns a buffer.

Is it possible to return the blob as text or as a string using Sequelize? Or will i need to loop through the array of objects and convert them?

Thanks for the help!

Similar code:

```
await findAll({
  where: {
    date: { $gte: sevenDaysAgo },
    newsSource: sourceList,
  },
  order: ['date'],
  raw: true,
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you can use a sequelize getter for this. Depending on the size of the buffer, this may be a very bad idea.

```
  const Employee = sequelize.define('employee', {
    picture: {
      type: Sequelize.BLOB,
      allowNull: false,
      get() {
        return this.getDataValue('picture').toString('utf8'); // or whatever encoding is right
      },
    },

  });
```

modified from [here](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-definition.html#helper-functions-for-use-inside-getter-and-setter-definitions).

Comment: Is there any way to do this when the raw option is set to true?

Comment: I'm going to accept the answer since it solves for dataValues. However, a better answer would be if there is a way to handle on the raw json object via sequelize. Not sure if that is supported though